# The toilet paper has run out/I've run out of toilet paper; I've used all the toilet paper up

Tags: word-usage

If someone in the restroom runs out of toilet paper and that person calls out to a person outside (at home),what will sound natural:

> The toilet paper has run out.
>
> I've run out of toilet paper.
>
> I've used all the toilet paper up.
>
> The toilet paper is all used up.

Do these sentences sound natural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your sentences

> The toilet paper has run out.

is ambiguous: has the toilet roll run away?

---

> I've run out of toilet paper.

does work well.

---

> I've used all the toilet paper up.

is misphrased, it should be

> I've used up all the toilet paper.

---

The last one

> The toilet paper is all used up.

Is poor construction.

---

But, saying there is no toilet paper is a statement of fact, not of need. What you could say is

> Can you please bring me some more toilet paper?

Answer (score 2):

The most natural sounding one is the second one:

> I've run out of toilet paper.

The first one is arguably as natural.

The third one is ok too, but I would change it to:

> I've used up all the toilet paper

The last one doesn't sound natural to me at all.